# Custom `FloatingTitleTextInputField` not accepting some property of TextInput in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, components, custom-component

I have create custom `FloatingTitleTextInputField` Component in my react-native project and it is working fine

below is my `floating_title_text_input_field.js` file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Animated, StyleSheet, TextInput, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {string, func} from 'prop-types';

export default class FloatingTitleTextInputField extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    attrName: string.isRequired,
    title: string.isRequired,
    value: string.isRequired,
    updateMasterState: func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {value} = this.props;
    this.position = new Animated.Value(value ? 1 : 0);
    this.state = {
      isFieldActive: false,
    };
  }

  _handleFocus = () => {
    if (!this.state.isFieldActive) {
      this.setState({isFieldActive: true});
      Animated.timing(this.position, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 150,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  _handleBlur = () => {
    if (this.state.isFieldActive && !this.props.value) {
      this.setState({isFieldActive: false});
      Animated.timing(this.position, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 150,
      }).start();
    }
  };

  _onChangeText = updatedValue => {
    const {attrName, updateMasterState} = this.props;
    updateMasterState(attrName, updatedValue);
  };

  _returnAnimatedTitleStyles = () => {
    const {isFieldActive} = this.state;
    return {
      top: this.position.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [14, 0],
      }),
      fontSize: isFieldActive ? 11.5 : 15,
      color: isFieldActive ? 'white' : 'dimgrey',
      textAlign: 'center',
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={[Styles.titleStyles, this._returnAnimatedTitleStyles()]}>
          {this.props.title}
        </Animated.Text>
        <TextInput
          value={this.props.value}
          style={Styles.textInput}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onFocus={this._handleFocus}
          onBlur={this._handleBlur}
          secureTextEntry={false}
          placeholderStyle={Styles.placeholderStyle}
          onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomColor: 'white',
    height: 50,
    marginVertical: 4,
  },
  textInput: {
    fontSize: 15,
    marginTop: 5,
    secureTextEntry: false,
    // marginStart: 10,
    // marginEnd: 10,
    // fontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium',
    color: 'white',
  },
  placeholderStyle: {},
  titleStyles: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // fontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium',
    // left: 3,
    // left: 4,
  },
});
```

but I'm facing below issue in above code

- I'm not able to set `placeholder` text in center
- when i used `secureTextEntry={true}` and `password={true}` it is not working
- When i set `keyboardType` to `email-address` it is not opening keyboard with email

Can anybody help me to solve these above issue

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to set placeholder text in center .  -  meaning the Animated.Text ? try to add width 100% .  Or set the container justifyContent & alignItems to 'center'

Comment: @Eran thanks for the reply let me try this